# why “Multi-statement transaction required more than 'max_binlog_cache_size' byte s of storage” exception just happened in parts of the slaves

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL cluster composed of one master and 5 slaves, and we just find three of the slaves met the following errors and both  max_binlog_cache_size and binlog_cache_size are the same to all of the nodes in the cluser , my question is why the master and the other two slaves didnt have the excption ? what the possibles this  situation happened?

"Could not execute Update_rows event on table xxxxx; Multi-statement transaction required more than 'max_binlog_cache_size' bytes of storage; increase this mysqld variable and try again, Error_code: 1197; handler error HA_ERR_RBR_LOGGING_FAILED; the event's master log mysql-bin.223903, end_log_pos 2326335819, Error_code: 1197"

Comment: If you are using statement-based binlog, and the data on each replica are different, then a given event could affect more rows on some replicas, and exceed the binlog cache size.

Comment: This question is fine, but it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com. It's not a code problem, and that's the requirement per the [Help Center on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Bill thank you for your advice, I would moved it to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286838/why-multi-statement-transaction-required-more-than-max-binlog-cache-size-byte

Comment: @Bill thanks Bill,  I confirmed the format is row , and BTW may I know why statement-based binlog could cause the data on each replica are different,?

Comment: I'm saying _if_ the data is already different on some replicas, then there's a chance that a statement-based binlog event would match more or fewer rows on that replica, and therefore there's a chance the size of a transaction would be larger.

Comment: i got it , thank you .